# update nested object in ElasticSearch using spark

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

How do I update a nested object in elasticsearch using Spark?

My data structure is as below

```
"tweet" : {
   "id" : "",
   "user" : [
  "user1":{},
  "user2":{}
]
}
```

I want to add a new user to existing user (i.e appending an element to the array). Here the user type is nested.